# Blocking production lines in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, csv

I have the following code that works great, but takes 40 mins to 1 hours to finish the task. It has at least 30 rules for blocking lines, and 30k+ orders to check. I'm new to Python (3 months working with it), so I don't know what can I change to make it run faster. The version in my computer is Python 2.7.9.

```
import codecs
import re

def find_word(text, search):
   result = re.findall('\\b'+search+'\\b', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
   if len(result)>0:
      return True
   else:
      return False

with codecs.open('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/BloqueoLinea/DATA/FO.txt','r',encoding = 'utf-8') as FO:
   finalorder = FO.readlines()
with codecs.open('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/BloqueoLinea/DATA/Table-Familias.txt','r',encoding = 'utf-8') as familias:
   list_familias = familias.readlines()

fo = ''
with codecs.open('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/BloqueoLinea/DATA/data.txt','w',encoding = 'utf-8') as data:
   for forder in finalorder:
      order = forder.split(';')
      orden = [order[0],order[1],order[15],order[24],order[2],'','']
      for familia in list_familias:
         fam = familia.split(';')
         if order[2] in fam[0]:
            orden[5] = fam[1]
            orden[6] = fam[2]
            fo = ';'.join(orden)
            data.write(fo+'\n')
with codecs.open('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/BloqueoLinea/DATA/data.txt','r',encoding = 'utf-8') as cross:
   cr = cross.readlines()
with codecs.open('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/BloqueoLinea/App_Data/BloqLines.txt','r',encoding = 'utf-8') as bloqueos:
   block = bloqueos.readlines()
with codecs.open('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/BloqueoLinea/DATA/nodos.txt','r',encoding = 'utf-8') as node:
   nodos = node.readlines()
with codecs.open('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/BloqueoLinea/DATA/Table-Lineas.txt','r',encoding = 'utf-8') as listlineas:
   tlines = listlineas.readlines()
count = 0
fileblock = codecs.open('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/BloqueoLinea/DATA/Restricciones_Ruteo.txt','w',encoding = 'utf-8')
for forder in cr:
   fo = forder.split(';')
   for bloqueo in block:
      check = bloqueo.split(';')

      if 'True' in check[0]: #Primero comprobar si la regla se aplica o no
         fam87 = check[5].lower()
         fam87 = fam87.capitalize()
         est = check[6].lower()
         est = est.capitalize()

         #Logica taxativo
         clinea = 0
         lista = []
         ap = lista.append
         for line in tlines:
            if check[7] in line:
               nline = line.split(';')
               lin = nline[1]
         for line in tlines:
            nline = line.split(';')
            if lin in nline[1]:
               if line in lista:
                  pass
               else:
                  nline = line.split(';')
                  ap(nline[0])

         #Fam87
         if forder.find(check[5]) >= 1 or (forder.find(fam87)) >= 1:
            if forder.find(check[6]) >= 1 or (forder.find(est)) >= 1:  #Si EstCom coincide con bloqueo actual
               if fo[1] in check[2]: #Si ITEMREP coincide bloqueo actual
                  for nodo in nodos:
                     nod = nodo.split(';')
                     if check[2] in nodo: #Si parametro de ITEMREP coincide en nodo actual
                        if bool(check[9]):
                           for item in lista:
                              if nod[3] in item:
                                 clinea += 1
                                 ub = lista.index(item)
                                 del lista[ub]
                           if clinea > 1: 
                              if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Revisar si parametro linea coincide en nodo actual
                                 count += 1
                           elif clinea == 1:
                              pass
                        else:
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Revisar si parametro linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                  if count >= 1:
                     fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                     count = 0
               elif  check[2] == '': #Cuando no hay ITEMREP
                  for nodo in nodos:
                     if fo[1] in nodo:
                        nod = nodo.split(';')
                        if bool(check[9]):
                           for item in lista:
                              if nod[3] in item:
                                 clinea += 1
                                 ub = lista.index(item)
                                 del lista[ub]
                           if clinea > 1: 
                              if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                                 count += 1
                           elif clinea == 1:
                              pass
                        else:
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                  if count >= 1:
                     fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                     count = 0
            #No hay EstCom, pero hay ITEMREP
            elif fo[1] in check[2] and (check[6] == ''): #Si ITEMREP coincide con bloqueo actual
               for nodo in nodos:
                  if check[2] in nodo: #Si parametro de ITEMREP coincide en nodo actual
                     nod = nodo.split(';')
                     if bool(check[9]):
                        for item in lista:
                           if nod[3] in item:
                              clinea += 1
                              ub = lista.index(item)
                              del lista[ub]
                        if clinea > 1: 
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                        elif clinea == 1:
                           pass
                     else:
                        if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                           count += 1
               if count >= 1:
                  fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                  count = 0
            elif check[2] == '' and check[6] == '': #Cuando no hay ITEMREP ni EstCom
               for nodo in nodos:
                  if fo[1] in nodo:
                     nod = nodo.split(';')
                     if bool(check[9]):
                        for item in lista:
                           if nod[3] in item:
                              clinea += 1
                              ub = lista.index(item)
                              del lista[ub]
                        if clinea > 1: 
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                        elif clinea == 1:
                           pass
                     else:
                        if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                           count += 1
               if count >= 1:
                  fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                  count = 0

         #Familia N1
         elif fo[5] in check[3] and (check[5] == ''):
            if fo[2] in check[6]:  #EstCom
               if fo[1] in check[2]: #ITEMREP
                  for nodo in nodos:
                     if check[2] in nodo: #ITEMREP
                        nod = nodo.split(';')
                        if bool(check[9]):
                           for item in lista:
                              if nod[3] in item:
                                 clinea += 1
                                 ub = lista.index(item)
                                 del lista[ub]
                           if clinea > 1: 
                              if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                                 count += 1
                           elif clinea == 1:
                              pass
                        else:
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                  if count >= 1:
                     fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                     count = 0
               elif check[2] == '': #No hay ITEMREP
                  for nodo in nodos:
                     if fo[1] in nodo:
                        nod = nodo.split(';')
                        if bool(check[9]):
                           for item in lista:
                              if nod[3] in item:
                                 clinea += 1
                                 ub = lista.index(item)
                                 del lista[ub]
                           if clinea > 1: 
                              if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                                 count += 1
                           elif clinea == 1:
                              pass
                        else:
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                  if count >= 1:
                     fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                     count = 0
            #Cuando no hay EstCom, pero hay ITEMREP
            elif fo[1] in check[2] and (check[6] == ''): #Si ITEMREP coincide con parametro de bloqueo
               for nodo in nodos:
                  if check[2] in nodo: #Si ITEMREP coincide en nodo actual
                     nod = nodo.split(';')
                     if bool(check[9]):
                        for item in lista:
                           if nod[3] in item:
                              clinea += 1
                              ub = lista.index(item)
                              del lista[ub]
                        if clinea > 1: 
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                        elif clinea == 1:
                           pass
                     else:
                        if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                           count += 1
               if count >= 1:
                  fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                  count = 0
            elif check[2] == '' and check[6] == '': #No hay ITEMREP ni EstCom
               for nodo in nodos:
                  if fo[1] in nodo:
                     nod = nodo.split(';')
                     if bool(check[9]):
                        for item in lista:
                           if nod[3] in item:
                              clinea += 1
                              ub = lista.index(item)
                              del lista[ub]
                        if clinea > 1: 
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                        elif clinea == 1:
                           pass
                     else:
                        if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                           count += 1
               if count >= 1:
                  fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                  count = 0

         #Familia N2
         elif fo[6] in check[4] and (check[3] == '') and (check[5] == ''):
            if fo[2] in check[6]:  #EstCom
               if fo[1] in check[2]: #ITEMREP
                  for nodo in nodos:
                     if check[2] in nodo: #ITEMREP
                        nod = nodo.split(';')
                        if bool(check[9]):
                           for item in lista:
                              if nod[3] in item:
                                 clinea += 1
                                 ub = lista.index(item)
                                 del lista[ub]
                           if clinea > 1: 
                              if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                                 count += 1
                           elif clinea == 1:
                              pass
                        else:
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                  if count >= 1:
                     fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                     count = 0
               elif check[2] == '': #Cuando no hay ITEMREP
                  for nodo in nodos:
                     if fo[1] in nodo:
                        nod = nodo.split(';')
                        if bool(check[9]):
                           for item in lista:
                              if nod[3] in item:
                                 clinea += 1
                                 ub = lista.index(item)
                                 del lista[ub]
                           if clinea > 1: 
                              if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                                 count += 1
                           elif clinea == 1:
                              pass
                        else:
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                  if count >= 1:
                     fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                     count = 0
            #Cuando no hay EstCom, pero hay ITEMREP
            elif fo[1] in check[2] and (check[6] == ''): #Si ITEMREP coincide con parametro de bloqueo
               for nodo in nodos:
                  if check[2] in nodo: #Si ITEMREP coincide en nodo actual
                     nod = nodo.split(';')
                     if bool(check[9]):
                        for item in lista:
                           if nod[3] in item:
                              clinea += 1
                              ub = lista.index(item)
                              del lista[ub]
                        if clinea > 1: 
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                        elif clinea == 1:
                           pass
                     else:
                        if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                           count += 1
               if count >= 1:
                  fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                  count = 0
            elif check[2] == '' and check[6] == '': #No hay ITEMREP
               for nodo in nodos:
                  if fo[1] in nodo:
                     nod = nodo.split(';')
                     if bool(check[9]):
                        for item in lista:
                           if nod[3] in item:
                              clinea += 1
                              ub = lista.index(item)
                              del lista[ub]
                        if clinea > 1: 
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                        elif clinea == 1:
                           pass
                     else:
                        if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                           count += 1
               if count >= 1:
                  fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                  count = 0

         #Cuando no hay parametro para ninguna Familia, se sigue a bloquear EstCom
         elif fo[2] in check[6] and (check[4] == '') and (check[3] == '') and (check[5] == ''): #EstCom
            if fo[1] in check[2]: #ITEMREP
               for nodo in nodos:
                  if check[2] in nodo: #ITEMREP
                     nod = nodo.split(';')
                     if bool(check[9]):
                        for item in lista:
                           if nod[3] in item:
                              clinea += 1
                              ub = lista.index(item)
                              del lista[ub]
                        if clinea > 1: 
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                        elif clinea == 1:
                           pass
                     else:
                        if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                           count += 1
               if count >= 1:
                  fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                  count = 0
            #Si no existe parametro de ITEMREP
            elif check[2] == '':
               for nodo in nodos:
                  if fo[1] in nodo:
                     nod = nodo.split(';')
                     if bool(check[9]):
                        for item in lista:
                           if nod[3] in item:
                              clinea += 1
                              ub = lista.index(item)
                              del lista[ub]
                        if clinea > 1: 
                           if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                              count += 1
                        elif clinea == 1:
                           pass
                     else:
                        if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                           count += 1
               if count >= 1:
                  fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
                  count = 0

         #Cuando no hay Familias, y no hay EstCom, bloquear por ITEMREP
         elif fo[1] in check[2] and (check[6] == '') and (check[4] == '') and (check[3] == '') and (check[5] == ''):
            for nodo in nodos:
               if fo[1] in nodo:
                  nod = nodo.split(';')
                  if bool(check[9]):
                     for item in lista:
                        if nod[3] in item:
                           clinea += 1
                           ub = lista.index(item)
                           del lista[ub]
                     if clinea > 1: 
                        if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                           count += 1
                     elif clinea == 1:
                        pass
                  else:
                     if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Linea coincide en nodo actual
                        count += 1
            if count >= 1:
               fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
               count = 0

print ('Finished')
fileblock.close()
```

At first I tried making some functions, but it started running slower, so I removed those functions and placed them in the code.

Basically, the code reads many text files. Some are static, but the FO.txt, nodos.txt and BloqLines.txt are different every day. When implemented, this code is supposed to run every morning.

It checks the rules (in BloqLines.txt) checks the orders (FO.txt gets some changes for data that it's needed and creates data.txt) and after checking with rules applies or not, it creates the Restriccion_Ruteos.txt and that's it.

If possible, how can I improve the performance of this code?

---

Samples from input files. Omitting the original files that are edited in the code.

BloqLines.txt :

```
True;Restringe  GLV IREP4801 por G3U;IREP4801;;;;;G4_UNI;;False
True;Restringe Angostos ME por el MC2;;;;ang;Expo;MC2_GUE;;False
True;Restringe Anneal para CGL;;;ANN;;;G2_JUV;;False
```

data.txt :

```
Orden00005990;IREP1554;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
Orden00005991;IREP1554;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
Orden00005992;IREP1554;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
Orden00005993;IREP1554;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
Orden00005994;IREP1554;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
Orden00005995;IREP1554;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
Orden00005996;IREP1554;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
Orden00005997;IREP1554;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
Orden00005998;IREP1555;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
Orden00005999;IREP1555;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
Orden00006000;IREP1555;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
Orden00006001;IREP1555;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
Orden00006002;IREP1555;Red Comercial;1;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD
```

Table-Lineas.txt:

```
ING_MAQ;INGMAQ;0;INGMAQ;ING_MAQ
COMP_SLB_TTC;COMP;0;COMP;COMP_SLB_TTC
MC1_GUE;MC;1;GUE;MC1_GUE
MC2_GUE;MC;1;GUE;MC2_GUE
MC3_CHU;MC;1;CHU;MC3_CHU
PREPA_GUE;PREPA;2;GUE;PREPA_GUE
SKP_GUE;SKP;2;GUE;SKP_GUE
SKP3_CHU;SKP;2;CHU;SKP3_CHU
SKP4_CHU;SKP;2;CHU;SKP4_CHU
DEC_PSQ;DEC;3;PSQ;DEC_PSQ
DEC_UNI;DEC;3;UNI;DEC_UNI
DEC1_CHU;DEC;3;CHU;DEC1_CHU
DEC2_CHU;DEC;3;CHU;DEC2_CHU
```

nodos.txt:

```
IREP1554Ruta_1_CUST_1;IREP1554;TEIREP1554_CUST_1;CUST;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;servicio;propaga;codproceso
IREP1554Ruta_1_DEC3_CHU_1;IREP1554;TEIREP1554_DEC3_CHU_1;DEC3_CHU;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;servicio;propaga;codproceso
IREP1554Ruta_1_ING_PT_1;IREP1554;TEIREP1554_ING_PT_1;ING_PT;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;servicio;propaga;codproceso
IREP1554Ruta_1_MC3_CHU_1;IREP1554;TEIREP1554_MC3_CHU_1;MC3_CHU;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;servicio;propaga;codproceso
IREP1554Ruta_1_NULL_1;IREP1554;NULL;NULL;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;servicio;propaga;codproceso
IREP1554Ruta_1_PT_1;IREP1554;TEIREP1554_PT_1;PT;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;servicio;propaga;codproceso
IREP1555Ruta_1_CUST_1;IREP1555;TEIREP1555_CUST_1;CUST;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;servicio;propaga;codproceso
IREP1555Ruta_1_DEC3_CHU_1;IREP1555;TEIREP1555_DEC3_CHU_1;DEC3_CHU;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;servicio;propaga;codproceso
IREP1555Ruta_1_ING_PT_1;IREP1555;TEIREP1555_ING_PT_1;ING_PT;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;servicio;propaga;codproceso
IREP1555Ruta_1_MC3_CHU_1;IREP1555;TEIREP1555_MC3_CHU_1;MC3_CHU;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;servicio;propaga;codproceso
IREP1555Ruta_1_NULL_1;IREP1555;NULL;NULL;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;servicio;propaga;codproceso
IREP1555Ruta_1_PT_1;IREP1555;TEIREP1555_PT_1;PT;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;servicio;propaga;codproceso
```

FO.txt:

```
Orden00005990;IREP1554;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Mas;44.835;44.835;44.835;0;0;20151130;20151130;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2015-11;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Mas;44.835;Comerciales;1;IREP1554;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;11
Orden00005991;IREP1554;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Mas;123.69;123.69;123.69;0;0;20151231;20151231;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2015-12;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Mas;123.69;Comerciales;1;IREP1554;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;12
Orden00005992;IREP1554;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Cus;40.296;40.296;40.296;0;0;20160131;20160131;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2016-01;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Cus;40.296;Comerciales;1;IREP1554;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;1
Orden00005993;IREP1554;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Mas;89.04;89.04;89.04;0;0;20160131;20160131;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2016-01;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Mas;89.04;Comerciales;1;IREP1554;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;1
Orden00005994;IREP1554;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Cus;90.187;90.187;90.187;0;0;20160229;20160229;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2016-02;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Cus;90.187;Comerciales;1;IREP1554;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;2
Orden00005995;IREP1554;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Mas;89.775;89.775;89.775;0;0;20160229;20160229;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2016-02;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Mas;89.775;Comerciales;1;IREP1554;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;2
Orden00005996;IREP1554;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Cus;97.637;97.637;97.637;0;0;20160331;20160331;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2016-03;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Cus;97.637;Comerciales;1;IREP1554;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;3
Orden00005997;IREP1554;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Mas;99.435;99.435;99.435;0;0;20160331;20160331;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2016-03;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Mas;99.435;Comerciales;1;IREP1554;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;3
Orden00005998;IREP1555;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Mas;42;42;42;0;0;20151130;20151130;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2015-11;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Mas;42;Comerciales;1;IREP1555;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;11
Orden00005999;IREP1555;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Mas;21;21;21;0;0;20151231;20151231;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2015-12;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Mas;21;Comerciales;1;IREP1555;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;12
Orden00006000;IREP1555;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Mas;42;42;42;0;0;20160131;20160131;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2016-01;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Mas;42;Comerciales;1;IREP1555;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;1
Orden00006001;IREP1555;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Cus;21.559;21.559;21.559;0;0;20160229;20160229;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2016-02;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Cus;21.559;Comerciales;1;IREP1555;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;2
Orden00006002;IREP1555;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;Mas;42;42;42;0;0;20160229;20160229;30;VirtualRep;Primeras;Rep;Red Comercial;1-Decapado;2016-02;000001;482;Committed;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto_Red_Rep_Mas;42;Comerciales;1;IREP1555;2015-11-23 12:43:39;0203;2
```

Table-Familias.txt:

```
B_RCD_SKP_Ang;LAC;RCD;ANG;RCD SKP Angosto;B_RCD_SKP_Ang
B_RCD_SKP_Rto;LAC;RCD;RTO;RCD SKP Resto;B_RCD_SKP_Rto
B_RCD_sSKP_Ang;LAC;RCD;ANG;RCD sSKP Angosto;B_RCD_sSKP_Ang
B_RCD_sSKP_Rto;LAC;RCD;RTO;RCD sSKP Resto;B_RCD_sSKP_Rto
B_RCD_TEM_Ang;LAC;RCD;RCD TEM;RCD Temple Angosto;B_RCD_TEM_Ang
B_RCD_TEM_Rto;LAC;RCD;RCD TEM;RCD Temple Resto;B_RCD_TEM_Rto
C_RFC_LAV;LAF;RFC;RFC;RFC LAV;C_RFC_LAV
C_RFC_MAQ;LAF;RFC;RFC;RFC MAQ;C_RFC_MAQ
C_RFC_MAQ_TNS;LAF;RFC;RFC;RFC MAQ TNS;C_RFC_MAQ_TNS
C_RFC_sLAV;LAF;RFC;RFC;RFC sLAV;C_RFC_sLAV
D_RFR_Anc_sTNS;LAF;RFR;ANCHO;RFR Ancho sTNS;D_RFR_Anc_sTNS
D_RFR_Anc_TNS;LAF;RFR;ANCHO;RFR Ancho TNS;D_RFR_Anc_TNS
D_RFR_Ang_LAV_sTNS;LAF;RFR;ANG LAV;RFR Angosto LAV sTNS;D_RFR_Ang_LAV_sTNS
```

Restricciones_Ruteo.txt:

```
BloqLine(Orden00001443,DEC3_CHU)
BloqLine(Orden00001444,DEC3_CHU)
BloqLine(Orden00001445,DEC3_CHU)
BloqLine(Orden00001446,DEC3_CHU)
BloqLine(Orden00002095,CGL_PSQ)
BloqLine(Orden00002095,G1P3_JUV)
BloqLine(Orden00002095,G2_JUV)
BloqLine(Orden00002095,G2_UNI)
BloqLine(Orden00002095,G4_UNI)
BloqLine(Orden00002095,G5_MVA)
BloqLine(Orden00002096,CGL_PSQ)
BloqLine(Orden00002096,G1P3_JUV)
BloqLine(Orden00002096,G2_JUV)
BloqLine(Orden00002096,G2_UNI)
BloqLine(Orden00002096,G4_UNI)
BloqLine(Orden00002096,G5_MVA)
BloqLine(Orden00002097,CGL_PSQ)
BloqLine(Orden00002097,G1P3_JUV)
BloqLine(Orden00002097,G2_JUV)
BloqLine(Orden00002097,G2_UNI)
BloqLine(Orden00002097,G4_UNI)
```

Comment: You could defiantly do with some functions, if it were me I'd favour 1 function over 10 minuet on something that takes 40 minuets to run, anyway... And welcome to CR! Hope you get some nice answers!

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same, but with just 1 simple rule, it took 20 minutes to make the file, so I decided to delete the function. And it was just to block 15 lines. It should have been faster, but it wasn't.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish just by tracing the code. Could you include a sample line from each input and output file?

Comment: @200_success I included some sample lines for the input files. Output files is e.g. BloqLine(Orden0000xxxx,MC2_CHU)

Comment: To get anywhere, we also need sample lines from `FO.txt`, `Table-Familias.txt`. The final file `Restricciones_Ruteo.txt` seems to only be written, but we should have some sample lines as to what you expect for output as well.

Comment: @holroy I added the sample lines of the files.

Comment: What is `check[2]`, in your sample files it is empty, but it heavily used throughout your code?  And what is `fo[1]`?

Comment: Could you also please give us typical number of lines in the different files? I'm wondering if you should switch around order of which files to read when, but that does depend on how many lines usually are in each of your files.

Comment: Check[2] goes for ITEMREP as Representative Item, it's a special code that can be give or not. It's heavily used in the code for checking if it's available and make some matches using it.

Comment: Running the program on the sample files in Rev 7 causes a `NameError: name 'lin' is not defined` at `if lin in nline[1]:`.

Comment: As for number of lines, the FO/data has at least 35-45k lines. nodos.txt has over 300k lines. Table-Familias and Table-Lineas has between 110-120 lines. BloqLineas.txt has 45 lines right now, it can change if the user adds more rules. And Restricciones_Ruteo.txt, right now has 8k lines, but it can change according to what lines can be blocked or nor.

Comment: @200_success well, that's weird. I'm running right now the code and didn't showed any error

Comment: could it be better if a upload the samples files to mediafire so you can used them???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In comments you state the following on lines in the various files:

> As for number of lines, the FO/data has at least 35-45k lines. nodos.txt has over 300k lines. Table-Familias and Table-Lineas has between 110-120 lines. BloqLineas.txt has 45 lines right now, it can change if the user adds more rules. And Restricciones_Ruteo.txt, right now has 8k lines, but it can change according to what lines can be blocked or nor.

As I see it, there is a dual issue in your code:

- *You read each and every file into memory* – You read at least 500K lines into memory. That is a lot of memory, and your computer is most likely switching memory most of the time
- *Enormous amount of loops* – Your main loop, `for forder in cr:`, does a secondary loop on the blocking rules, `for bloqueo in block:`, and ends up in doing a tertiary loop, `for nodo in nodos:` for a variety of `if` statements. Considering approx 40K entries in `cr` with 45 blocking rules and for each of these you do 300K loops within `nodos`, that means you are going to execute 540 000M loops doing your search, before output'ing a blocking line.

  For each of these loops you do a lot of splitting, and searching in a newly built regex, and other somewhat costly stuff.

I'm not surprised it is slow. You should really reconsider how you are processing your files. You would most likely get a major speedup if you could switch the loops around and have the `nodos`-loop as the main loop and *not* read it entirely into memory. This would allow for the rest of your code to accelerate. And at the same time move the blocking rules to the inner most looping level.

Simplifying your immense `if` structure would also most likely help, as you actually seem to do about the same in all of the branches.

### Ugly restructure attempt

I started copying out similar blocks out of your original code, into make-shift functions (which won't work due to variable scoping and such). Doing this I found the following make shift functions to exist:

```
def refactor_first():
    nod = nodo.split(';')
    if check[2] in nodo: #Si parametro de ITEMREP coincide en nodo actual
       if check[9]:
          for item in lista:
             if nod[3] in item:
                clinea += 1
                ub = lista.index(item)
                del lista[ub]
          if clinea > 1: 
             if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Revisar si parametro linea coincide en nodo actual
                count += 1
          elif clinea == 1:
             pass
       else:
          if find_word(nod[3], check[7]): #Revisar si parametro linea coincide en nodo actual
             count += 1


def fileblock_write():
   if count >= 1:
     fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))
     count = 0


def fo1_in_nodo():
    for nodo in nodos:
        if fo[1] in nodo:
            refactor_first()
    fileblock_write()

def check2_in_nodo():
    for nodo in nodos:
        if check[2] in nodo: #ITEMREP
            refactor_first()
    fileblock_write()

def all_in_nodo():
    for nodo in nodos:
        refactor_first()                      
    fileblock_write()
```

Using these non-working functions your massive `if` block is simplified to this:

```
    #Fam87
    if forder.find(check[5]) >= 1 or (forder.find(fam87)) >= 1:
        if forder.find(check[6]) >= 1 or (forder.find(est)) >= 1:  #Si EstCom coincide con bloqueo actual
           if fo[1] in check[2]: #Si ITEMREP coincide bloqueo actual
              all_in_nodo():

           elif  check[2] == '': #Cuando no hay ITEMREP             
              fo1_in_nodo()

        #No hay EstCom, pero hay ITEMREP
        elif fo[1] in check[2] and (check[6] == ''): #Si ITEMREP coincide con bloqueo actual        
           check2_in_nodo()

        elif check[2] == '' and check[6] == '': #Cuando no hay ITEMREP ni EstCom
           fo1_in_nodo()

     #Familia N1
     elif fo[5] in check[3] and (check[5] == ''):
        if fo[2] in check[6]:  #EstCom
           if fo[1] in check[2]: #ITEMREP             
              check2_in_nodo()

           elif check[2] == '': #No hay ITEMREP             
              fo1_in_nodo()

        #Cuando no hay EstCom, pero hay ITEMREP
        elif fo[1] in check[2] and (check[6] == ''): #Si ITEMREP coincide con parametro de bloqueo          
           check2_in_nodo()

        elif check[2] == '' and check[6] == '': #No hay ITEMREP ni EstCom
           fo1_in_nodo()

     #Familia N2
     elif fo[6] in check[4] and (check[3] == '') and (check[5] == ''):
        if fo[2] in check[6]:  #EstCom
           if fo[1] in check[2]: #ITEMREP              
              check2_in_nodo()

           elif check[2] == '': #Cuando no hay ITEMREP        
              fo1_in_nodo()

        #Cuando no hay EstCom, pero hay ITEMREP
        elif fo[1] in check[2] and (check[6] == ''): #Si ITEMREP coincide con parametro de bloqueo        
           check2_in_nodo()

        elif check[2] == '' and check[6] == '': #No hay ITEMREP           
           fo1_in_nodo()

     #Cuando no hay parametro para ninguna Familia, se sigue a bloquear EstCom
     elif fo[2] in check[6] and (check[4] == '') and (check[3] == '') and (check[5] == ''): #EstCom
        if fo[1] in check[2]: #ITEMREP
           check2_in_nodo()

        #Si no existe parametro de ITEMREP
        elif check[2] == '':            
           fo1_in_nodo()

     #Cuando no hay Familias, y no hay EstCom, bloquear por ITEMREP
     elif fo[1] in check[2] and (check[6] == '') and (check[4] == '') and (check[3] == '') and (check[5] == ''):           
        fo1_in_nodo()
```

All the `if` branches here ends up in either: `check2_in_nodo()`, `fo1_in_nodo` or `all_in_nodo()`. And these vary by only one thing and that is if they check whether `check[2]` or `fo[1]` or all is present in the current `nodo` element. If present they all call the same `refactor_first()` which ends up doing the `find_word(nod[3], check[7])`, and if this is found you do the `fileblock.write("BloqLine(%s,%s)\n" % (fo[0],check[7]))`.

This should be possible to restructure into a nicer and possibly faster structure:

- First of all, the `lista` should be prebuilt outside of the loops, as it is constant relative to the blocking rules. This can be copied at will for the next loop, but do not regenerate it all the time
- At start of loop you should precompile the regex as you always check against the `check[7]` word. Store this as `check_pattern`
- You should also break out of the loop immediately when `count == 1`, as you'll then *always* do a `fileblock.write()`. No need to check the rest of `nodos` in this case
- If doable, avoid doing the `del lista[ub]` as that is somewhat expensive
- Replace `find_word` with a cheaper `check_pattern.search(nod[3])`
- Instead of storing the entire `nodos` list, it seems like you can get away with only storing the `nod[3]` element. This should be done when reading in the nodos file. This will reduce memory issues and remove the need for some of the splits possibly.

### In summary

I'm not going to do the entire refactoring, but you should focus on the following:

- Check if you can switch around the loops, so that you can have the largest file(s) only on disk, and not entirely in memory
- If that is not feasible, then strip away all data you can, and only leave the neccessary data in the variable you are working with
- Precompile regex as early as possible, and the same for static lists like `lista`
- If you're not able to restructure loops, make functions for the `fo1_in_nodo()`, `check2_in_nodo` and `all_in_nodo` make-shift functions
- Simplify the massive if structure which triggers the make-shift functions. This won't affect performance much, but it can help you understand what you are doing more easily

But at the end of the day, you also seriously need to reconsider what you are doing, because checking 40 000 orders (from cr) against 300 000 nodos seems just plain wrong, something you should be using a database to solve. This is a massive amount of data you are processing.

Comment: About your last comment, all this that I'm doing was already being done in Access, but for whatever reason, my boss wants this made in Python and added to a library of scripts the company has. I did said that the database was the better option, but didn't listen. I will try to make the best changes possibles that you suggested. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JoshuaCazares, why do you use stuff like `fo[1] in check[2]`. Do you really need to check if the fo-value is a substring (or contained) with the check-value? Or would `fo[1] == check[2]` be equivalent? Using the sample files my example statement would be similar to `IREP1554 in ''`, and that is not very likely to happen...

Comment: Well, what the f... have I been doing here, I didn't catch that mistake. Seems like it was something I forgot to correct from the first version of the code.

Comment: Just as a question, I remade the code, and it ended at 100 lines, but still performing slow. Is there a way to free memory?

Comment: You do have the possibility to call garbage collectors, or `del nodos`, and some other variants. But to get a proper answer, please post a follow up question with your new revised code, and some input data so that we can run through some tests, and help you further.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to give a frank assessment: I think that this code is effectively unmaintainable, and that you would be better of rewriting it from scratch, because **you are using the wrong tool for the job**.  Essentially, you want to combine data from five tables to produce a query result.  There are better ways to do that than writing 400 lines of `for` loops and `if` blocks.  This is a solved problem in computing, and there is no sense in reinventing the wheel.

### Option A: SQL

A lot of what you are doing is basically equivalent to a [join](/questions/tagged/join) in SQL.  For example, this code…

> ```
> fo = ''
> with codecs.open('data.txt','w',encoding = 'utf-8') as data:
>    for forder in finalorder:
>       order = forder.split(';')
>       orden = [order[0],order[1],order[15],order[24],order[2],'','']
>       for familia in list_familias:
>          fam = familia.split(';')
>          if order[2] in fam[0]:
>             orden[5] = fam[1]
>             orden[6] = fam[2]
>             fo = ';'.join(orden)
>             data.write(fo+'\n')
> with codecs.open('data.txt','r',encoding = 'utf-8') as cross:
>    cr = cross.readlines()
> ```

… is just a textbook example of a LEFT OUTER JOIN operation:

```
CREATE VIEW CrossOrders AS
    SELECT Order.col0 AS order_id
         , Order.col1 AS item_rep
         , Order.col15 AS est_com
         , Order.col24
         , Order.col2
         , COALESCE(Familia.col1, '')
         , COALESCE(Familia.col2, '')
        FROM Order
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Familia
                ON Order.col2 = Familia.col0;
```

(I don't know what all of your columns represent.  I've used identifiers like `col24` as placeholders, but of course you should define your database tables with column names that make sense, like `quantity` or `supplier`).

I'm not going to reverse-engineer all of your code, but I would be willing to bet that the entire program can be reduced to the `VIEW` I defined above, plus one giant SQL query.

So how would you go about rewriting the code?  If you already have a database at your company, such as [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) or [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), then great, use that instead of your .txt files.

If you don't have a database handy, then just install [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite), which is an SQL engine that doesn't require a database server.  Import your .txt files to SQLite, either [using the `sqlite` shell](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv) or [Python code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).  **Even if you have to re-create a new SQLite database from scratch with every batch run, import all of the CSV data, and throw away the database after the query, it's still worth it for the massive productivity gains.**  The resulting program would have a chance of being maintainable.  It would likely be faster as well, as SQL engines are specifically optimized to do this kind of thing.

### Option B: PANDAS

If you prefer to avoid SQL and stick to Python and semicolon-delimited files, then there are libraries that can help you.  In particular, [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) is designed to work with tabular data sets.  The first page of code would look more like this:

```
import pandas as pd

finalorders = pd.read_csv('FO.txt', encoding='UTF-8', sep=';', header=None)
familias = pd.read_csv('Table-Familias.txt', encoding='UTF-8', sep=';', header=None)
orden = pd.merge(
    left=finalorders, right=familias, how='left',
    left_on=0, right_on=2
)[['0_x', '1_x', 15, 24, '2_x', '1_y', '2_y']]

normalize_caps = lambda s: s.lower().capitalize()
blocks = pd.read_csv('BloqLines.txt', encoding='UTF-8', sep=';', header=None, converters={5:normalize_caps, 6:normalize_caps})
tlines = pd.read_csv('Table-Lineas.txt', encoding='UTF-8', sep=';', header=None)
```

Personally, I'd prefer to go with SQL than PANDAS for this task.  Even if you aren't using a database now, I'm guessing that you will eventually wish that you had one, because you're already part way to building a database system yourself anyway.

### Additional observations

There are other general issues with your program.

- Use more list comprehensions.  Not only do they make your code more compact and readable, they also reduce the number of variables floating around in your code.  (And you have a *lot* of similarly named variables like `node`, `nodos`, and `nod`, which makes it confusing.)
- Each row of data is "stringly typed".  That is, you're keeping each row as a semicolon-delimited string.  As a result, you have `line.split(';')` littered all over the code, which is both inefficient and hard to follow.

  What you want to do instead is get it into 2D array form as soon as possible:

  ```
  with codecs.open('Table-Familias.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as familias:
      list_familias = [line.rstrip().split(';') for line in familias]
  ```
- As specified in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), indentation should be 4 spaces, not 3.  Since whitespace is significant in Python, this is a pretty strong convention that you should follow.
- You're using the `in` keyword rather carelessly in many places.

  For example, when you wrote `if order[2] in fam[0]:`, you really meant `if order[2] == fam[0]:`.  Also, instead of `if 'True' in check[0]:`, you should write `if 'True' == check[0]`.  In those places, `in` would do a substring search rather than an exact string match.  The code happens to work, but it's sloppy.

  Elsewhere, you're doing `if check[7] in line:`, which means that you are searching for `check[7]` across *all* of the columns of that row.  This is a very unconventional kind of join condition: you really want to search for `check[7]` in column 0 or column 4, and you should write the code accordingly.

Comment: I also would use SQL for this, believe me when I say that I commented that it was far better doing it in databases, but since the server where the code is gonna be implemented doesn't have access to any kind of database, my opinion wasn't heeded.

Comment: I saw your comment after writing this answer. Anyway, both options I presented are technically still Python, and don't require a DB server.

Answer (score 2):

One fairly substantial optimization is removing extra computations.

Lets look at:

```
def find_word(text, search):
    result = re.findall('\\b'+search+'\\b', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    if len(result)>0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Your use of `findall` is wasteful, as you only check if there's at least 1 match, you don't really care about the quantity/matches.

Thus we can rewrite it as follows:

```
def find_word(text, search):
    return re.search('\\b'+search+'\\b', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None
```

and have the exact same effect at much lower cost, since `search` returns as soon as any match is found.

This should have a pretty substantial performance impact considering the number of times you call this function inside loops.

As for the code...readability has much to be desired. Having tons of nested conditionals/loops is really hard to read, so I would strongly recommend writing functions for each major chunk.

Comment: Yeah, I have an issue, because I have to check several parameters, to see if there's a blank then do something, or if the parameter is incomplete check possible matches, so I need to know how to reduce the quantity of nested conditionals.

Comment: As for the moment, I already left my office, and can't make any changes in the code. Tomorrow I will post again if the code runs faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate approach related to optimising your code, if my previous answer doesn't help enough, and if you can't switch to using either a database, like sqlite, or use pandas. Before explaining the alternate I would like to recap that your current algorithm is something along the following lines:

- *Read all files into memory*, and preprocess the `FO.txt` and `Table-Familias.txt` into the new `data.txt` which are also read
- *Main loop: For each orders in `data.txt`*: (approx 40K entries)

  - *Secondary loop: For each blocking rule*: (approx 40-50 rules)
  - Continue with next order, if rule not active
  - If active blocking rule:

    - Rebuild *Logica taxativo*: `lista`_
    - Various large if tests, before doing:
    - *Tertiary loop: For all nodo in nodos*: (approx 300K entries)

      - Simple logic, fix `lista`, and output to file

### Alternate approach using an intermediary file

The alternate approach is to split this into two, using an intermediary file. That is use the above approach, but instead of doing the tertiary loop, you write just those parameters needed for modifying the `nodos` list into a new file. Doing this you can skip loading `nodos` in the first pass, and do a memory efficient one pass of `data.txt` where you process it line by line.

And then you add a new pass where you read this intermediary file into memory, and do a memory efficient one pass of `nodos.txt` matching only those needed and doing the output to the final file.

Doing this you would simplify from potentially having a time and/or space complexity of \$O(n\cdot m)\$, where \$n\$ is number of lines in `data.txt` and \$m\$ is number of lines in `nodos.txt`, into having having a time complexity of \$O(n+m)\$, and a space complexity of \$\theta (p)\$ where p is lines in the intermediary file. This can have a huge impact on execution time.

To change from reading all lines into doing the memory efficient version, you change the first `for` loop into:

```
with codecs.open(`data.txt', 'r', ...) as orderfile, codecs.open('tmp_file.csv', ...) as tmpfile:
    for order in orderfile:
        # Process the order
```

And similar for the other one. This also allows for a little better file handling as Python keeps track of the file handles, and you don't need to. :-)

### Assign tuples to variables

Another point related to readability would be to do something like the following:

```
active_rule, title, item_repr, _, something = bloqueo.split()
```

Then you can replace the cryptic `check[2]` with a more meaningful variable. Similar can of course also be done instead of using `fo[7]` and friends...

This alternate approach in addition to some of the other comments related to only read what you need, and avoid the `in` when you actually mean `==`, and prebuilding regexps, and other suggestions in other answers should make your code a lot faster, and easier to maintain and understand.